# How to make a component reusable by making it as a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am working on a repo where I have got three different react.Js projects, Among which I need to make a component as NPM module.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking about how to publish your component as an npm package? If that is what you are asking this might help https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Comment: @aaditya.. I am more looking towards pushing one of my components as npm package, I am not sure my question make sense.

Comment: Your question makes sense. This resource makes it incredibly easy. I used it myself. https://medium.com/@adrianli/the-idiot-s-guide-to-publishing-a-react-component-to-npm-2b66b1ac03e0

Comment: If you want a reusable component to use across all the 3 projects, your question does make sense.

Comment: You can publish your component on npm registry itself, or you can create your private registry as well.